# Kotlin JVM - Char MAX_CODE_POINT - Unresolved Reference

Tags: kotlin

According to this document: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char/index.html

`Char` has a companion object property `MAX_CODE_POINT`. But, when I try to access it, I get:

```
$ kotlinc-jvm
Welcome to Kotlin version 1.3.50 (JRE 1.8.0_212-b04)
Type :help for help, :quit for quit
>>> Char.MAX_CODE_POINT
error: unresolved reference: MAX_CODE_POINT
Char.MAX_CODE_POINT
     ^

>>> Char.Companion.MAX_CODE_POINT
error: unresolved reference: MAX_CODE_POINT
Char.Companion.MAX_CODE_POINT
               ^
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you using Kotlin/Native? The documentation states that this property is defined in Kotlin/Native only.

Comment: @jsamol You are 100% right! I missed that.

Comment: I updated the title to say JVM. If you submit an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char/-m-a-x_-c-o-d-e_-p-o-i-n-t.html) the `MAX_CODE_POINT` property is defined in Kotlin/Native only.